# Spark: saveAsTextFile without compression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compression

By default, newer versions of Spark use compression when saving text files. For example:

```
val txt = sc.parallelize(List("Hello", "world", "!"))
txt.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")
```

will create files in `.deflate` format. It's quite easy to change compression algorithm, e.g. for `.gzip`:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress._
val txt = sc.parallelize(List("Hello", "world", "!"))
txt.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

But is there a way to **save RDD** as a plain text files, i.e. **without any compression**?

Comment: Try setting `mapred.output.compress` to `false`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can see the **text file in HDFS without any compression** with this code.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("App name")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapred.output.compress", "false")
val txt = sc.parallelize(List("Hello", "world", "!"))
txt.saveAsTextFile("hdfs/path/to/save/file")
```

You can set all Hadoop related properties to `hadoopConfiguration` on `sc`.

Verified this code in Spark 1.5.2(scala 2.11).

Comment: Tested on local filesystem instead of HDFS and Scala 2.10 instead of 2.11, and it works like a charm! Thanks!