# How to read a part-00000.deflate file on linux

Tags: apache-spark

I have written a spark word count program using below code:

```
package com.practice

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object WordCount {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark   = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
    val input   = args(0)
    val output  = args(1)
    val text    = spark.sparkContext.textFile(input)
    val outPath = text.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val words   = outPath.map(w => (w,1))
    val wc      = words.reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x+y))

    wc.saveAsTextFile(output)
  }
}
```

Using spark submit, I run the jar and got the output in the output dir:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --master local[2] --class com.practice.WordCount sparkwordcount_2.11-0.1.jar file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/sample file:///home/hmusr/ReconTest/inputdir/output
```

Both the input and output files are on local and not on HFDS.
In the output dir, I see two files: `part-00000.deflate  _SUCCESS`.
The output file is present with .deflate extension. I understood that the output was saved in a compressed file after checking internet but is there any way I can read the file ?

Comment: Isn't `deflate` a hadoop compatible format? You should be able to read it with `hdfs dfs -text /path/to/part-00000`

Comment: The file is on local (dir created on linux)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178566/215945

Comment: you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263907/spark-saveastextfile-without-compression

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

cat part-00000.deflate | perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)'

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some more info.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly and saved me a lot of time! Thanks!